# php curl: posting form in tribalwars

Tags: php, curl

First of all, I'm sorry for this question being so specific, but that is because I really don't know what could be going wrong. I'm trying to submit a form with php `cURL` on the website tribalwars.net. This is my code in a class method environment:

```
$post_data = array();
$form = $this->html->find('form[action*=command]')[0];
$inputs = $form->find('input');
foreach ($inputs as $input) {
   $post_data[trim($input->name)] = trim($input->value);
}
var_dump($post_data);
echo $url = 'http://en'.$this->world.'.tribalwars.net'.$form->action;
$referer = 'http://en'.$this->world.'.tribalwars.net/game.php?village='.$this->currentVillage.'&try=confirm&screen=place';
parent::doCurl($url, $referer, $post_data);
```

`$this->html` stores the html in a simple_html object of the current page, which is the one you receive when you want to attack someone on tribalwars. The only thing that doesn't work yet that I'm trying to do with this code, is confirming the attack by clicking a button. The function `doCurl` I made myself has always worked for me putting other forms on tribalwars and other sites. Since I'm including every post variable which could possibly be required by means of a `foreach ($inputs as $input)`, I really don't understand what could be going wrong (there are no `select`s on the page).

So what other possibilities are there for a cURL form submit not to work? I think there is no javascript involved.

Comment: You sure you're not going to XSS-attack them?

Comment: what do you mean by cross site scripting??

Comment: Are you making this form to post something in a manner which TribalWars wouldn't aprove? Cheating..

Comment: I'm working at a premium feature which would allow you clicking on a bar on top of your browser to connect with tribal wars and also allow you to send a response attack when there are incoming attacks.